# Python, Como deixar a pessoa colocar um numero e com esse numero colocar essa mesma quantidade de perguntas

Tags: python

Será que é possível fazer um sistema assim em Python, tipo vamos supor em um sistema de colégio, se eu colocar

```
materias = print(input("Digite o número exato de matérias que há nesta série: "))
```

o que é preciso pra repetir a mesma quantidade que a pessoa colocar tipo assim

```
print(input("Digite o nome da matéria: "))
```

e eu quero repetir essa pergunta e separar cada uma em uma "string" para depois colocar a media de tudo e várias outras coisas , mas o foco é isso, eu queria saber se tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Java ou python?

Comment: python..........

Comment: a edição de perguntas é algo comum aqui no SO, acho que não há necessidade de editar a pergunta agradecendo alguém pela edição da pergunta. :s

Comment: Ok entao! .....

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc quer armazenar uma lista de matérias como string, seria isso?

Comment: sim, e isso....

Comment: Como você já percebeu pelas respostas que teve: sim, é possível. Mas a sua pergunta não é muito boa para o formato deste site porque é ampla demais. Dá pra fazer o que você quer de inúmeras formas, inclusive criando interfaces gráficas (o que seria mais apropriado para uma grande quantidade de dados de entrada). Sugiro especificar mais a pergunta (se a sua dúvida é como fazer um laço para ler várias entradas do console, faça *essa* pergunta diretamente).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não percebi bem a parte das médias, mas aqui está uma solução para o teu problema de armazenamento de matérias:

```
materias = []
qtd_materias = None
while not isinstance(qtd_materias, int):
    try:
        qtd_materias = int(input("Digite o numero exato de materias que ha nesta serie: "))
    except:
        print('Por favor digite um inteiro')

for _ in range(qtd_materias):
    materias.append(input("Digite o nome da materia: "))

print('As materias sao:', ', '.join(materias))
```

Comment: Nice! mas ai só vai ficar tudo na parte materias tem como separar?

Comment: Separar como? Não percebo como queres separar @Genezis. Podes dar um exemplo?

Comment: Se for para ficar como texto, já editei a resposta para isso @Genezis

Answer (score 3):

Se sua intenção é apenas ter uma lista de matérias armazenadas como string, você só precisara usar um lista, e o Python tem uma certa facilidade em relação a manipulação de listas.

Veja um exemplo com base no que você descreveu:

```
i = 0
materias = []
quantidadeMaterias = input("Digite o numero exato de materias que ha nesta serie: ")

while i < quantidadeMaterias:
    materia = raw_input("Digite a descricao da materia: ")
    materias.append(materia)
    i += 1

for m in materias:
    print(m)
```

Entrada (Numero de matérias que há na série)

> 2

Entrada das matérias

> Portugues
>   Matematica

Saída das matérias

> Portugues
>   Matematica

Eu apenas precisei criar uma lista que é a variável `materias` e em seguida populei ela através do loop.

[Leia mais sobre listas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 5, in <module>
    while i < quantidadeMaterias:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Basta converter o retorno de input() para int: `quantidadeMaterias = int(input(...))`

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas acho que você precisa de uma lista de matérias e um dicionário para cada matéria. O resultado seria algo assim:

```
    [{"nome": "Matemática",
          "serie": "quinto ano",
          "professor": "Paulo",
          "alunos":[{"nome": "Maria Antônia", "media": 7}, {"nome":"Renato", "media": 8}],
          "mediaTotal":7.5},

     {"nome": "Matemática",
          "serie": "sexto ano",
          "professor": "Rosa",
          "alunos":[{"nome": "Suzana", "media": 7}, {"nome":"Claudia", "media": 8}],
          "mediaTotal":7.5}]
```

Para montar essa estrutura, pensei em um código tipo assim:

```
    nMaterias = int(input("digite o número exato de matérias que há nessa série"))
    materias = []
    for i in range(nMaterias):
        materia = {
                    "nome": input("Qual o nome da matéria %s: " %(i+1)),
                    "serie": input("Qual a série da matéria %s: " %(i+1)),
                    "professor": input("Qual o nome do professor da matéria %s: " %(i+1)),
                    "alunos": None,
                    "mediaTotal": input("Qual a média da matéria %s: " %(i+1)),
                    }
        materias.append(materia)
    print (materias)
```

Bom, claro que precisaria de um trabalho maior para fazer outro loop para preencher cada aluno e a media total poderia ser feita com um cálculo rápido das médias preenchidas.

Além disso, no seu código, não da pra armazenar print() em uma variável. Primeiro se armazena o input na variável e depois se dá um comando print().

Answer (score 0):

Se percebi bem, podes fazer assim:

```
materias = []
n_materias= int(input("Digite o número exato de matérias que há nesta série: "))
for i in range(n_materias):
     materias.append(input("Digite o nome da matéria: "))
print(materias)
```

Se correres o código vai fazer algo assim:

> Digite o número exato de matérias que há nesta série: <kbd>2</kbd>
>
> Digite o nome da matéria: <kbd>Matemática</kbd>
>
> Digite o nome da matéria: <kbd>Inglês</kbd>
>
> ['Matemática', 'Inglês'] #conteudos do array materias